# Why do I get NaN from this function?

Tags: typescript, function

I'm trying to calculate the total price from an array with multiple objects, but somehow my function returns NaN.

It will show all the different prices if i use this.totalPrice = this.items[i].amount, but when i add the + to get the total sum, it returns NaN. Does anyone here know why?

```
 items: ICartItem[] = [];
 totalPrice: number;

getTotalPrice(){
    for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
      this.totalPrice += this.items[i].amount * this.items[i].movie.price;
      console.log(this.totalPrice);
    }
  }
```

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0:
amount: 4
movie: {id: 18, name: "Le fabuleux destin d'Amélie Poulain", description: "null", price: 100, imageUrl: "null", …}
1:
amount: 3
movie: {id: 16, name: "The Dark Knight", description: "null", price: 199, imageUrl: "null", …}
```

I expect this.totalPrice to return the total sum of all the objects in the array.

Comment: Show the full ```this.items``` array, please.

Comment: Who knows... you haven't shown us a complete example.

Comment: You need to include a complete, runnable example that reproduces your problem. There are too many unknowns in your code for us to comment meaningfully.

Comment: @Jacquesジャック: The `*` operator performs automatic numeric conversion.

Comment: @meagar I added more info!

Comment: WHAT? I never knew that. Granted, I don't think I've ever tried to multiply a string and a number either, but still.

Comment: I'm *guessing* that `this.totalPrice` is not initialized properly.

Comment: ^ like @ziggywiggy says,  if you don't set to 0, `undefined + 10 = NaN`

Comment: @ziggywiggy I missed that in his example, `this.totalPrice` is in fact, not initialized.

Comment: You're right! I changed it to totalPrice = 0; and now it's working! Thank you guys =)

Comment: @Jacquesジャック: Yeah, all the arithmetic operators perform numeric conversion, except for `+`, since it's overloaded for concatenation.

Comment: That's not JS syntax. What language are you using?

Comment: @ziggywiggy That's cool. It's funny when you never run into something because your code is always type safe. But it's cool. I think I'll add it as an interview question, lol. Also, it looks like typescript.

Comment: Yeah, if you say a value is of type `number` but don't initialize it, the real type is `number | undefined`.  Enable the `strict` compiler flag and this will **REALLY HELP** a lot to catch errors & typos like this!